# How to split a word into letters in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to do the following:

Input string:

```
input = 'Hello'
```

Output string:

```
output = 'H,e,l,l,o'
```

I understand you can do `list(input)`, but that returns a list and I wanted to get the string rather than the list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
In [1]: ','.join('Hello')
Out[1]: 'H,e,l,l,o'
```

This makes use of the fact that strings are iterable and yield the individual characters when iterated over.

Answer (score 6):

```
outputstr = ','.join(inputstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since NPE already provided the `','.join('Hello')` method, I have a different solution (though it may not be more Pythonic):

```
inputStr, outputStr = 'hello', ''
for char in inputStr: outputStr += char + ','
print outputStr[:-1]
```

Output: `'h,e,l,l,o'`.

Comment: @Legend There, changed it :P

Comment: It's also terribly slow: since Python strings are immutable, every string concatenation involves creating a new string and copying the two concatenated strings into it.

Comment: The fact that it's harder to read and much easier to get wrong (as evidenced by the fact that you, a more experienced developer than the OP, got it wrong…) is probably even more of a problem than the slowness. Remember TOOWTDI.